# Flexbox Conatiner inline taking up remaining width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a main `<div>` container, consisting of 3 child `<div>`'s:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-left">.. some markup ..</div>
  <div id="child-flex>
    <div id="flex-child-1">
    <div id="flex-child-2">
    <div id="flex-child-3">
    <div id="flex-child-4">
  </div>
  <div id="child-right">.. some markup ..</div>
</div>
```

- `child-left` is `display:inline` and `float:left`, with a fixed
  set `width`
- `child-right` is `display:inline` and `float:right`,
  with a fixed set `width`
- `child-flex` is `display:inline-flex`

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Get the `child-flex` container to display inline in between `child-left` and `child-right`, and take up any remaining space.
2. Get all the `flex-child-` children to have equal width within the `child-flex` container. At the moment I have set `flex: 1 0 auto;`, but it does not seem to work. Could be because of the parent?

Comment: It would better if you posted the `css` as `css`, not in sentences. Also, you might get more help if you create a graphic that visually shows what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is there a reason why not use flex for all children?

Comment: provide fiddle for fast solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use flexbox throughout...in this case, use `display:flex` on the parent and then make the `#child-flex` flex-container a *nested* flexbox.

No need to use floats at all.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XdqjNQ)

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
#child-right,
#child-left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: pink;
}
#child-flex {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-left">some markup</div>
  <div id="child-flex">
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child-right">some markup</div>
</div>
```